# How can I export data from Java to Excel or Word if documents have different forms?

Tags: java, excel, ms-word

I need to know how to export data from Java to Excel. My customer gave me a form and asked me export the data to their report form. They can give me a different form. How can I do this?

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you mean by "different form."

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know how to export data from Java to Excel.

Easiest way is to create a comma separated values (csv) file, which you import into Excel.

> My customer gave me a form and asked me export the data to their report form.

Hard to say without seeing the form, but you can copy values from the Excel csv page to the report form page within the same Excel workbook.  You could automate this with a Visual Basic script.

> They can give me a different form.

And you can copy values from the Excel csv page to the new report form page within the same Excel workbook.  You could automate this with another Visual Basic script.

Comment: i need use java, and my customer can give me other design form such as some time salary report have different column with business report. I need to know with different form design how can i do it automatic

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using the Apache POI library (http://poi.apache.org/).  The library was created with the sole intent of reading and writing Office Open XML standards (OOXML) and Microsoft's OLE 2 Compound Document format (OLE2).

Answer (score 0):

Can you assume presence of Open Office or MS Office on System?

Best way to do that would be via Mail merge. Setup a mail merge template and provide data in an excel/csv file from java program.

Once dta has been generated, formatted reports can be generated via mail merge. And since its template, it can be very easily be modified in Office itself.